# передача в процедуре в качестве параметра var TObject

Tags: delphi

Где-то читал, что ссылочным типам не нужно ставить `var`.

Есть у меня процедура:

```
procedure SetObjectData(var AObject: TObject; var AIndex: integer);
begin
  if AObject is TFDQuery then
    with (Aobject as TFDQuery) do
      Params[0].Values[AIndex] := DT_START;

  TObjectQueue.Enqueu(AObject);
  AObject := TObjext.Create;
  AIndex := 0;
end;
```

И правильно ли я понимаю, что при создании нового объекта внутри этой процедуры я получаю новую ссылку и тогда мне нужно использовать `var`? А может переписать этот код? А то ссылка на ссылку не очень.

Comment: Нет. При использовании ключевого слова `var` Вы не получаете новую ссылку. Применение данного слова означает *передача параметра по ссылке*, т.е. в процедуру передается ссылка на объект, с которым Вы вольны делать все, что угодно. В том числе освобождать и создавать. [Занимательное чтиво](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29). P.S. можно также использовать вариант, данный в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 3):

```
function SetObjectData(AObject: TObject; var AIndex: integer): TObject;
begin
  if AObject is TFDQuery then begin
    with (AObject as TFDQuery) do begin
      Params[0].Values[AIndex]:= DT_START;
    end;
  end;

  TObjectQueue.Enqueu(AObject);
  result := TObject.Create;
  AIndex:= 0;
end;

...
obj := SetObjectData(obj, i);
...
```

Comment: Зараннее простите за некропостинг =) но имхо - это не ответ на вопрос, и если в курсе что будет вот при таком действе `Pointer(AObject)=@SomeOtherPointer` при передаче как у вас в примере то пожалста поясните.Мне правда не известно что произойдет, но логика подсказывает что не получится без `var` сделать такой финт, **т.е. изменить саму ссылку**

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Да, не получится. Такой код изменит то, куда указывает параметр функции внутри функции, но на переменной, использованной в качества параметра при вызове функции, это не отразится.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Насчет ответ/не ответ. Автор переживал по поводу `var` параметра. Я показал вариант кода, который делает то же самое, но без `var` перед параметром `TObject`.

Comment: `Насчет ответ/не ответ.` я не совсем верно понял вопрос, прочел по диагонали и додумал о своем, в моей голове вопрос звучал как "нужно ли использовать var у ссылочных типов данных", так что да, вы правы и изначально у вас именно ответ... =)

Comment: obj := SetObjectData(obj, i); Это быстрее, чем SetObjectData(var obj, i);?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете `var` то по сути у вас получается, что в метод как-будто бы передаются эти самые переменные:

```
SetObjectData(someObj, i); 

procedure SetObjectData(var AObject: TObject; var AIndex: integer);
begin
  if someObj is TFDQuery then
    with (someObj as TFDQuery) do
      Params[0].Values[i] := DT_START;

  TObjectQueue.Enqueu(someObj);
  someObj := TObjext.Create;
  i := 0;
end;
```

Если же вы НЕ используете `var` то в метод передаются копии значений переменных и это выглядит вот так:

```
SetObjectData(someObj, i); 

procedure SetObjectData(AObject: TObject; AIndex: integer);
begin
  someObj_copy := someObj;
  i_copy := i;

  if someObj_copy is TFDQuery then
    with (someObj_copy as TFDQuery) do
      Params[0].Values[i_copy] := DT_START;

  TObjectQueue.Enqueu(someObj_copy);
  someObj_copy := TObjext.Create;
  i_copy := 0;
end;
```

и, как видите, по окончании метода, изменились только переменные внутри метода, а те что передавались снаружи остались неизменны.

Но!. здесь есть вот какой подводный камень, допустим вы в методе сделаете `FreeAndNil(someObj_copy)` - догадываетесь что произойдет? Объект на который указывают обе `someObj_copy` и `someObj` будет уничтожен, а указатель `someObj` останется и вы получите AccessViolation при попытке работы с ним (или что похуже).

Comment: Ох, не надо говорить слово "копии" в данном контексте. Давайте говорить "значения".

Comment: @Igor Пускай будет "копии значений". А чем вам "копии" не нравятся?

Comment: Потому что выражение "копия экземпляра класса" может быть неправильно понято.

Comment: Хорошо. Но слова "экземпляра класса" в ответе не фигурируют.

Comment: Полностью согласен с @Igor, у вас сказано `копии значений переменных`, `Var A : TObject;` Теперь когда я передам "копию **значения переменной**" **A**, я передам копию **экземпляра класса**, т.к. **А** это **экземпляр класса** TObject....

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков вам стоит быть внимательнее. Экземпляр класса <> значение переменной /указателя на него (`A : TObject`).

Comment: @Kromster Я осведомлен о ссылочных типах данных и какие именно типы данных в Delphi являются ссылочными, но это не для всех очевидно. Давайте пойдем дальше в комментариях чтоб вы поняли то о чем я говорю, `Var S:string`, что будет если я передам в функцию **S** `SomeFunct(S)`? а что будет если передам вот так `SomeFunct(S[1])` или так `SomeFunct(@S)` или вот так `SomeFunct(PChar(S))`? Строка ведь не объект? почему поведение как у объекта в некоторых случаях?